React native not starting
I have done everything to start my react native project.
When I run npx react-native start, I get this error
Could not move temporary workspace (C:\react_native_apps\testApp\recipieApp\recipieMain\appMain\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7
dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-184c717c-29c4-4863-ba7c-4418c8432239) to immutable location (C:\react_native_apps\testApp\recipieApp\recipieMain\appMain\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)
> Could not move temporary workspace (C:\react_native_apps\testApp\recipieApp\recipieMain\appMain\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15
a-184c717c-29c4-4863-ba7c-4418c8432239) to immutable location (C:\react_native_apps\testApp\recipieApp\recipieMain\appMain\android\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a)


I have ran all diagnoses given to me by chat gpt.nothing is working
I was expecting the code to run on my android emulator after running npx react-native start,
and selecting android from the menu, but this never works.

I take it this didn't help, i.e. the first result when researching your error for you

Thanks, for some reason that skipped my attention. It seemed to have helped.
